# Get a value of particular column from Database Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

table Structure:

```
         **Orders**
      OrderNumber (pk)
      IsApproved Boolean
```

i am creating a shipment. So before creating it , I want to check that whether the selected order is approved or not.

How to implement this ?

[image]

Comment: Have you even bothered to give it a go? Please do try and come back with specific problems and questions related to your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in gvShipment.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dr.Cells["Select"];
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
                {
                    IsApproved += dr.Cells["IsApproved"].Value.ToString() ;
                }
            }
        }
        if (IsApproved == "False")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This Order is not Approved.", "Message");
            return;
        }
```